# Problem converting FBX file into XNB

Tags: android, monogame, fbx, visual-studio

I create a Monogame Content Project to convert assets into XNB. For FBX file without texture there is no problem: the file is correctly converted and when I load XNB into my project everything is ok. 
The problem occours when i have associated to fbx file a texture map: in this case both FBX and PNG files are converted to XNB but when i try to load these XNB files into my project the following problem occours:

"ContentLoadException: Could not load Models/maze1 asset as a non-content file!" 
Note: maze1 is the XNB file that was converted from FBX.

How can I solve this problem? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: What platform are you testing on?

Comment: Sorry I totally forgot! I'm working with Visual Studio 2012 testing on Android

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Wiki](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/MonoGame-Content-Processing) the Content Pipeline for Android requires different steps and it seems does not yet work with MonoGame's own content project.

However it seems parts are already working (a bit). So a possible work around is to import the FBX model without textures, but including texture coordinates (UV's) and load the texture separately. Then apply the texture to the model yourself during run time.

Answer (score 0):

The Android file system is case sensitive.

Check that the filenames and paths match what the data is looking for. It's possible that the Models directory is lower-case on Android and therefore doesn't match the upper-case M in Model for example.